# How do I find all members who don't have a role? discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to find all members who don't have a specific role. Here's the code I could think of:

```
message.guild.members.forEach(member => if (!member.roles.cache.has('role id') {
  console.log("Doesn't have the role.")
}));
```

Comment: I do not know about discord, but I understand `message.guild.members` is an array,  in order to help you please show some sample data of `message.guild.members`

Comment: It's not an array it's a manager,`<Manager>.cache` is collection which is an extension of a map, either way their forEach method works pretty similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS sytnax is wrong, and you are interchanging `.cache` and no `.cache`

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if(!member.roles.cache.has(role_id) {
     console.log("Doesn't have the role");
  }
});
```

Also look at:

```js
const invalid =  message.guild.members.cache
    .filter(member => member.roles.cache.has(role_has));
```

forEach takes a callback, if you want to use an if statement you will still need the brackets

Comment: That second option works, but how do I found the length of the array? When I do invalid.length it returns undefined.

Comment: It's a collection which is an extension of the native Map class in JS, it has a size property instead of length. **invalid.size**